# C# code exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am absolute beginner in c# and I have no idea what is wrong with this code, a little help is needed

```
        try 
        {
            double[,] matrix = new double[2,2];
            String liczba = "85481";
            matrix[1,1] = double.Parse(liczba); 
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("general exception");
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("exceeded scope of variable");
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("variable converstion error");
        }
```

Comment: The only wrong, *it seems*,  would be catching base class exception first and then the specific later, it should be other way round, also ignoring the actual exception and just showing a message.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is whron"? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler helps you out a bit here. You will have two errors that look like this:

> A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type ('System.Exception')

You can't catch a more specific type of `Exception` after a less specific type.  From the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx), emphasis mine:

> ... the order of the catch clauses is important because the **catch clauses are examined in order**. Catch the more specific exceptions before the less specific ones. **The compiler produces an error if you order your catch blocks so that a later block can never be reached**.

All exceptions derive from `Exception` (`System.Exception`).  Re-order them to put the handler for `Exception` as the last `catch` clause and it will compile:

```
try
{
    double[,] matrix = new double[2, 2];
    String liczba = "85481";
    matrix[1, 1] = double.Parse(liczba);
}        
catch (OverflowException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("exceeded scope of variable");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("variable converstion error");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("general exception");
}
```